# Curso android avançado

Tags: android

Galera, alguém conhece alguma instituição que ofereça um curso de android avançado?

O que eu quero dizer com android avançado? Quero alguém que já tenha criado sua própria versão do android, que tenha alterado o fonte e mudado os builds, removido recursos e tal, parecido com oque as operadores de telefones fazem, algo bem baixo nível, e não criações de APP.

PS: Não sei se aqui é exatamente o lugar ideal para perguntar isso, mas enfim..

Comment: Acho que se a pergunta fosse escrita de outra maneira ela seria totalmente valida.

Comment: Está difícil de compreender ou postada no lugar errada?

Comment: É facil de compreender, mas da maneira que esta escrita leva ao off-topic. Se fosse algo, *"como criar o meu proprio sistema android"* seria valido, pedidos de cursos são off.

Comment: De fato não é o lugar adequado. O foco do site é colecionar Perguntas e Respostas objetivas sobre a programação em si, diferente de um fórum. Mas dê uma pesquisada na tag [tag:android], pode ser que você ache informações interessantes para complementar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Eu estava formulando uma resposta, mas vai demorar muito hehehe é muita coisa, todavia se tiver pratica com inglês o link é esse https://source.android.com/index.html ele ensina o passo a passo (recomendo JDK8 no 7 tem muitas dependencias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é fazer sua própria imagem Android, então sua parada é o projeto AOSP https://source.android.com/ . Mas não é coisa trivial. Já mexi com AOSP no passado, para alterar componentes-chave do Android (Bluetooth e kernel), então é factível.